# Get PHP mysql array in Jquery UI autocomplete source and separate each item with comma

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have mysql database and I have table from which I need to take entire row. Than I need to put that row in jquery ui autocomplete so I can call it with my input field. Problem is that I made array with all items from row but they need to be separated in jquery. So it can't be like this:

`[
    {"Location":"Zagreb"},
    {"Location":"Split"},
    {"Location":"Zadar"},
    {"Location":"Zlatar"},
    {"Location":"Osijek"}
 ]`

but it has to be like:

`"Split", "Zadar", "Zlatar", "Osijek"`

So my php:

```
$query = 'SELECT Location FROM locations';
                $result = mysqli_query ($link, $query);
                $rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$rows[] = $r;               
}



echo json_encode($rows);
```

And jquery autocomplete:

```
$( "#location1" ).autocomplete({
source: [ '<?php echo json_encode($rows);

 ?>' ]
});
```

Some tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your query you are appending each row array to $rows. You only want to append the value for the column Location:

```
$query = 'SELECT Location FROM locations';
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r['Location'];
}
```

Comment: Yes that's it. Thank you very much. 
And one thing for someone else who needs help. Remove [ '' ] from source because it's allready in php variable rows.